# Join 2 Table Variables in SQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, join, table-variable

How to join 2 table variables which are not consists of a foreign key column.

```
DECLARE @InventoryIDList TABLE(ID INT)
DECLARE @ProductSupplierIDList TABLE(ID INT)
```

Excepted output

```
@InventoryList
--------------
123
456
789
111

@ProductSupplierIDList
--------------
999
888
777
666

@InventoryList    ProductSupplierIDList
---------------------------------------
123             |        999
567             |        888
789             |        777
111             |        666
```

All are random data. I just want to combine the 2 table variable to look like above. I tried all the types of joins. But I need to have the upper mentioned output without having `null` values.

I tried the `CROSS APPLY`

```
SELECT *
FROM @InventoryIDList invList CROSS APPLY @ProductSupplierIDList prdList
```

But it gives me 5^2 number of elements as the result with duplicates.

Comment: You define with INTS, but the values are not?

Comment: What is your `JOIN` criteria?

Comment: @dfundako It was a mistake. I updated the question. Thanks

Comment: Thanks @HarshaW. Could you, however, please define your `JOIN` criteria? As you can see below, all 3 answers have taken the same route, however, without actually knowing, it is basically guess work. dfundako does raise a good point that if further values are added, it could/would change the `JOIN` results.

Comment: @Larnu Thanks for answering. I just wanted to append both the table var results and insert it in to a physical table which contains 2 cols same as the joined result. I just wanted to have a table structure which matches 1 st item in the first var and 1 st item in the 2nd var in order to look like a one row etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the IDs are not in sequential order and can be random, I would recommend using an Identity on the table variables and joining on that:

```
DECLARE @InventoryIDList TABLE(JoiningID INT IDENTITY(1,1), ID INT)
DECLARE @ProductSupplierIDList TABLE(JoiningID INT IDENTITY(1,1), ID INT)

INSERT INTO @InventoryIDList 
VALUES 
(123),
(456),
(789),
(111)

INSERT INTO @productsupplierIDList 
VALUES 
(999),
(888),
(777),
(666)


SELECT i.id, p.id
FROM @inventoryIDList i
INNER JOIN @productsupplierIDList p
    oN i.joiningid = p.JoiningID
```

Comment: It is worth noting that if you use this solution in a more persistent table structure, like a user object or temp table, if you error an insert and lose that identity value, this could cause a lot of issues.

Comment: Also you can set `JoiningID` as a primary key, so your joins will be more efficient. Also, shouldn't it be a full join?

Comment: @EvaldasBuinauskas It absolutely could be, depending on if there is ever uneven amounts of records in the tables. But OP says no NULL values to be included in the result data set.

Comment: Yes, I see your answer now (SO hadn't loaded it, apologies). My concern with adding the `IDENTITY` would be that those values would, initially, be assigned randomly. The OP is (likely) under the impression that the data is stored in the order they inserted it in, not in a heap. You could update the values of those IDs after adding the column, however, then you have the problem of having to do a sort operation based on *something*.

Answer (score 3):

I guess you need `Row_Number` and `Full Outer Join`, considering there is no relation between those 2 tables

```
SELECT I.ID,
       P.ID
FROM   (SELECT Rn = Row_number()OVER(ORDER BY ID),*
        FROM   @InventoryList) I
       FULL JOIN (SELECT Rn = Row_number()OVER(ORDER BY ID),*
                  FROM   @ProductSupplierIDList) p
              ON I.RN = P.RN
```

Comment: Would this work since the inventory IDs are not in numerical order?

Comment: @dfundako -It will work.. Also if you check the result, there is no particular order the results are joined..

Comment: The reason I ask is because the OP says the data is random. If you add 1 more value to each table, like an ID of 900 to Inventory and an ID of 100 to Product, the results then change a lot

Comment: @dfundako - Since the data is not related at all.. I highly doubt we should use `Inner Join`. So all 900 Inventories and 100 Products might be needed in result

Comment: Basically we are matching the 1st record in 1 table to the 1st record in the next table and so on.

Comment: Sorry, I clarified my comment. I didnt mean add 900 values and 100 values. I meant add 1 more value of 900 to the Inventory table and 1 more value of 100 to the Product table

Comment: @dfundako If you accept data is random then what matches up with what should not matter.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that the `JOIN` criteria is the same "row number" in ascending ID order:

```
WITH invList AS (
    SELECT *,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ID) AS RN
    FROM @InventoryIDList),
prdList AS (
    SELECT *,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ID) AS RN
    FROM @ProductSupplierIDList)
SELECT *
FROM invList IL
     JOIN prdList PL ON IL.RN = PL.RN;
```

Comment: I have the same comment for this solution as the one I already commented on. If the data is all random, how will ordering by ID work if you add more random values to the data sets?

Comment: @dfundako Quotiing myself here and emphasing the important words * **Assuming** that the JOIN criteria is the same "row number" in ascending ID order*. :)

Comment: Also, @dfundako, you keep making this comment, but the OP has already said that they **don't** have any kind of key. rather than shooting down everyone's answer thus far, could you post an answer instead that deals with the scenario of someone adding data to the table(s), without using any DDL changes please? Telling us there is a problem for a scenario, without a solution, doesn't help much. Especially when all 3 answers, thus far, have taken the same route. :)

Comment: No need to get saucy over someone asking a question about your code and how it will handle different scenarios.

Comment: @dfundako I'm not being saucy, I honestly would like to see how you would deal with the scenario you keep talking about.

Comment: My answer would be a good starting place... We were told data is random, not that we can't change DDL on a table variable.